# iOS: semi-infinite table

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've got a table with 1000 rows, only a few of the remotely located data for which I have on hand initially. How can I strategize my loading of row data over a slow data link to minimize the number of empty table cells that the user sees whole scrolling? My code tells my uitableview that there are 1000 rows and 1 section.

For instance let's say I fire off a request for 10 rows below to 10 that are visible, but then the user scrolls upward in the table. How do I cancel requests to save previous bandwidth?

Comment: how you are making requests, have you tried anything? please post that code too

Comment: I'm using nssession data tasks.